# Ionic 2, ¿utiliza Angular 2 o AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

Tengo entendido que no es lo mismo **Angular** que **AngularJS**, y que existe una gran confusión respeto a este tema en Internet. Por esta razón, me da más confianza realizar la siguiente pregunta acá, antes que buscar información en Internet.

***Ionic 2, ¿utiliza Angular2 o AngularJS?***

La pregunta responde a que quiero comenzar a estudiar Ionic, pero antes debo centrarme en aprender Angular o AngularJS (dependiendo de lo que me respondan).

Gracias.

Comment: Ionic 2 está basado en Angular2 (Angular a secas). Ionic 4 está basado en Web Components y en principio podrías utilizar cuaquier otro framework JavaScript.

Comment: Esta pregunta casi parece mejor para le chat que para el sitio en sí. No termino de entender cuál es la "gran confusión" en Internet sobre Angular o AngularJS, y una [simple búsqueda en la documentación de Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/concepts/) responderá a tu pregunta.

Comment: Me cansé de leer, en diferentes sitios, que Ionic 2 utiliza AngularJS y, en otros, que Ionic 2 utiliza Angular 2. En Youtube, un usuario hacia alusión justamente a esa confusión e información errónea que circula por la red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la [documentación oficial](http://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/concepts/):

> Ionic currently requires Angular in order to work at its full
>   potential. While you can still use the CSS portion of the framework,
>   you’ll miss out on powerful UI interactions, gestures, animations, and
>   other things. In the future, Ionic plans to become more agnostic in
>   order to support a broader variety of JavaScript frameworks.

Traducción breve: Ionic actualmente requiere Angular (no AngularJS) para sacarle todo el rendimiento. En el futuro se planea que sea más "agnóstico" para soportar una mayor variedad de frameworks.

Comment: Entendido. Gracias